# jQuery - how to send form, when I check whatever checkbox?

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a form, in which is about 10 checkboxes. When I want to send form after check some checkox, I do that this way:

```
$('input#checkbox1').live("click", function() {
    $('#my_form').submit();
});
```

How to do, that if I check whatever checkbox, so the form will be sent?

Comment: Please restate your question. I do not understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('input[type=checkbox]')` instead of `$('input#checkbox1')` should help.

Answer (score 1):

This code will submit everytime you check/uncheck any checkbox.

```
$(document).on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
   $('#my_form').submit();
})
```

This code will submit only if it's checked, on any checkbox

```
$(document).on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
   if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
      $('#my_form').submit();
   }
})
```

If you want to filter so that it doesn't attach to all checkbox, consider adding a class to the specified checkbox, and then use something like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".sendFormCheckbox", function() {
    $('#my_form').submit();
});
```